# SetState with react hook and redux after async call to axios API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm fetching products from a server with axios and  rendering data in **CatalogProducts** component like this :

```
const CatalogProducts = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    await props.getProducts();
  };

  useEffect(async () => {
    fetchProducts();
    setData(props.products);
  }, []);

  const { products } = props.products;

  const items = products.map((product, index) => {
    return (
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={index}>
        <CatalogProduct product={product} />
      </Grid>
    );
  });

  if (products.length === 0) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  } else {
    return (
      <Container maxWidth="xl" className={classes.root}>
        <Grid
          container
          direction="row"
          justify="center"
          alignItems="center"
          spacing={3}
        >
          {items}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    products: state.products
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getProducts: () => dispatch(actions.getProductsAction())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CatalogProducts);
```

I can acces the products data with **props.products** but when I want to access them using **data** variable, I don't know if it's a good idea to work with setData()?

Comment: By the time you set `data` as `props.products` the async action isn't done yet which means that `data` holds a stale value (the value of `props.products` before fetching). But why do you need data anyway? Just use `props.products` directly

Comment: Thank you for your response, i just want to know how can i updating the state of my component after fetching data from server, but actually i will use  **props.products**

Comment: You could setup an `useEffect` which triggers everytime `props.products` changes and updates `data`. `useEffect(() => setData(props.products), [props.products])`

Comment: it does an infinite loop when i console.log(data) .

Comment: Ziko did you try my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yeaah , thank you

Comment: @Ziko10 please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I try to do that by stack blocked me, can you show me how to do ?

Comment: @Ziko do you mean you stackoverflow doesn't allow you to mark an answer? Here is what to do to mark an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i already voted on your answer but stack show me this error "Your vote in now locked in unless this answer is edited "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your functional components you can use the new [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch) and [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector) features which is a easier to use.

Can you replace you CatalogProducts code with this, import the other necessary imports and try?

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
//other imports

const CatalogProducts = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const products = useSelector(state => state.products);
  console.log("Products: ", products);

  const fetchProducts = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(actions.getProductsAction());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, [fetchProducts]);

  const items = products.map((product, index) => {
    return (
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={index}>
        <CatalogProduct product={product} />
      </Grid>
    );
  });

  if (!products) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  } else if (products.length === 0) {
    return <div>No products found</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <Container maxWidth="xl" className={classes.root}>
        <Grid
          container
          direction="row"
          justify="center"
          alignItems="center"
          spacing={3}
        >
          {items}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    );
  }
};

export default CatalogProducts;
```

Sample [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-rexux-gifted-thunder-cpre6-8c9dk) using jsonplaceholder fake api.